# mongodb graphLookup not working in sharded collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My testcol collection looks as follow:

```
mongos> db.testcol.find().limit(3)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60b871854bea7a9df54f0594"), "ID" : "B1", "CID" : "B2", "DOC" : "Some info" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60b8718e4bea7a9df54f0595"), "ID" : "B3", "CID" : "B5", "DOC" : "Some info" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60b871994bea7a9df54f0596"), "ID" : "B5", "CID" : "B2", "DOC" : "Some info" }
mongos>
```

After sharding  testcol  I have realized $graphLookup is not working anymore:

```
mongos> db.testcol.aggregate([ { $graphLookup: { from: "testcol", startWith: "B1" , 
connectFromField: "ID", connectToField: "CID", as: "children" } } ])
2021-06-03T07:35:13.242+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "test.testcol cannot be sharded",
    "code" : 28769,
    "codeName" : "Location28769",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1622698513, 28),
    "$clusterTime" : {
            "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1622698513, 28),
            "signature" : {
                    "hash" : BinData(0,"RObEDuuK9uibPFj/MAoDwSyR3Lc="),
                    "keyId" : NumberLong("6939965305435193347")
            }
    }
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:580:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:673:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:260:9
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1062:12
@(shell):1:1
mongos>
```

According to the mongo docs $graphLookup is not accepting from as sharded collection , but
my collection become very big(6TB already) and it seems I cannot keep it unsharded , any suggestion on how to get my graph relations in sharded collection?

Comment: There are only 2 options - don't shard or don't use $graphLookup. I guess it's the later in your case. You will need to implement this functionality on the application level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MongoDB documentation since 3.4 ([source](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#sharded-collections)):

```
The collection can be sharded.
The fromCollection cannot be sharded.
```

*EDIT* ([source2](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27533?focusedCommentId=4094926&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-4094926)):

```
support for sharded "from" collections in $lookup and $graphLookup will be part of the upcoming 5.1 release.
```

Comment: I already mentioned it in my question... , but searching option   to solve it...

Comment: I think your question is not likely to get an answer other than the one you have or that Alex Blex gave.

Unless you change your data given Alex's advice, you are essentially hoping that the documentation is incorrect or developers have not found a secret way, which is unlikely.  You can monitor the progress of this feature here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27533?focusedCommentId=1613348&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel

Comment: There has been ann update:
```support for sharded "from" collections in $lookup and $graphLookup will be part of the upcoming 5.1 release.
```